# electron-forge: missing some dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Using: Windows 10, NMP 6.4.1, Node v10.13.0, GIT 2.8.4

A simple app to show IMDB records:
https://ide.c9.io/learnwithcolt/webdevbootcamp folder APIS / movie_search_app

Dowloaded to run locally on Windows. It runs ok.

When I run:

```
electron-forge init my-new-app

√ Checking your system
It looks like you are missing some dependencies you need to get Electron running.
Make sure you have git installed and Node.js version 6.0.0+
```

**package.json:**

```
    {
  "name": "imdb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

The same happens with other proyects. CMD is running as Administrator.

Comment: Are you trying to develop Electron on C9? Because that won't work or you at least won't be able to run Electron on C9.

Comment: No, sorry, is a local version that I downloaded. Post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The same happens with other proyects

Just with `electron-forge` or other CLI tools too? My guess is this is a `path` issue- electron forge can't find your Node/Git installations.

You can try `npx electron-forge init my-new-app` but that's a long shot.

Also, make sure you're using the correct version of Electron forge. There's a new one that's kinda broken right now.

> The master branch is a rewrite of Electron Forge that will eventually be the 6.x series. If you are looking for the 5.x series (the version currently published to NPM), please view the 5.x branch.

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge

Comment: Solved now! Thanks a lot! My Windows Path was C:\Program Files\Git instead of C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Working now!